# Immutable объекты во множествах

Tags: java

Почему в Set не следует сохранять ссылки на мутабельные объекты?

Comment: Потому что если изменить объект, то должен измениться и хеш, а хешсет он работает только для тех объектов, у которых хеш не меняется, ведь он по этому хешу и ищет объекты у себя.

Comment: А как на счет TreeSet?

Comment: TreeSet хранит объекты в каком то порядке. Суть его в том, что он использует сравнение элементов, чтобы понять, куда его у себя внутри положить относительно других элементов. Потому если вы меняете элемент, то есть его отношение (больше или меньше) с другими элементами меняется, то можно и вовсе не найти свой элемент после этого в TreeSet. В [доке](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) явно про это написано `Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals`

Comment: ну и вообще, сами по судите - Set - это коллекция уникальных элементов, без дубликатов. Что будет если сначала туда поместить 2 разных элемента, а потом один из низ изменить так, чтбы он стал дубликатом второго? - ваш Сет сломается на этом. Об этом в [доке](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) написано явно `Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. `

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

HashSet на то и Hash что в нем для уникальности используется HashMap внутри, изменив hash мы не найдем бакет в хеш мапе, а следовательно и в сете.
TreeSet , я так понимаю в джава нет механизма которые при изменении объекта в  TreeSet перестраивал деревья да и что делать если новый объект с таким же значением уже есть?